# For Doctrine ORM, why is DBAL needed in addition to PDO?

Tags: orm, pdo, doctrine-orm

I've been working with Doctrine 2 ORM for some time, and there's something I've never quite understood.

What purpose does the Doctrine DBAL (database abstraction layer) serve? PDO itself a database abstraction layer, so why can't the ORM work directly with PDO?

I'm not trying to find a way around using DBAL or anything. I've just never understood why the extra layer is needed, and can't seem to find a clear answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, PDO is a "data-access layer", not a "database abstraction layer". Meaning that you can switch databases and still make the same method calls, but PDO will not re-write sql queries to match the selected database or emulate any database functionality.

[Per PHP PDO docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php):

> PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer, which means that, regardless of which database you're using, you use the same functions to issue queries and fetch data. PDO does not provide a database abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing features. You should use a full-blown abstraction layer if you need that facility.

Comment: Thanks - that helps my understanding quite a bit about the relationship between the layers.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine2 actually supports some non-PDO databases so that is one reason.
It's also useful to look at the source code.  The Connection class (for example) has a nice:

```
public function insert($tableName, array $data)
```

Which inserts a new record complete with escaping.

Comment: Looking at the source code is a great idea, will help me walk through what's happening at each step